# Alterar um banco de dados Sql Server com Linq em ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linq

Olá, estou com uma tarefa onde preciso alterar a estrutura das tabelas em uma aplicação ASP.NET que utiliza Linq para trabalhar com as tabelas. Minha dúvida é: Existe uma situação onde tenho uma tabela no banco "Vendas" e outra "Produtos". Para conseguir vincular vários produtos em uma venda decidi criar uma tabela "Vendas_Produto". Ok, alterei no banco de dados diretamente no SSCM. Porém a aplicação já tem uma estrutura linq mapeada no arquivo .dbml e eu gostaria de saber como faço pra atualizar a alteração que fiz diretamente no banco de dados no arquivo .dbml fazendo com que a aplicação converse com o banco da maneira correta.

Comment: olá, dê uma olhada em *Migrations*, é usado para fazer alterações de estrutura
no seu caso se não tiver, pode apagar as entidades do seu modelo e gerar novamente, isso vai atualizar o teu modelo linq

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, apaguei e recriei tudo novamente. Funcionou certinho.